# Creating class of SQLite

Tags: c++, class, sqlite

I'm sorry, I'm showing too many lines of code but I just have a small problem.

Take a look at the code file, you'll see two areas which I marked via comment [1] and [2] (Maybe you'll need [3]).

When I run the program, because this is a console program so the screen will have something like:

```
Befor callback: 0 
After callback: 0
```

It should be `After callback: 99` that is what I need.

**My question is** Why doesn't `iResult` variable change after I modify it?

**Update 1**
The 1st agrument of callback function points to where (this) pointer (in [3])points to.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Are you sure the callback function is actually called?

Comment: Did you try to step through this with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I tried many times. The callback function is called. I alse used running step by step but I am not able to find out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `run_query` to execute your query, it assigned the result of the `sqlite3_exec` call to `iResult`. This overwrites the 99 with the result of the query, which is 0.

Comment: this might be the answer, but does it assist learning how to write good code, and prevent [BIG](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9183580/Epic_failures_11_infamous_software_bugs) [catastrophes](http://vu.bits-pilani.ac.in/ooad/Lesson2/topic3.htm)?

Comment: Thank you. Can you let me know how did you find out this? The Dark.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. I used a debugger to run your program. Saw that the 99 value was being set properly in the callback and that the object pointer was the same. That meant that the value was being set back in some way. That would be either be something writing to memory it shouldn't (like a buffer overflow) or something actually setting the value back. Luckily it was the latter - I just stepped out from the callback back through the sqlite stuff until I came to the `run_query` function. If that didn't work, I was going to set a data breakpoint on the value to see when it changed back.

Comment: Also, you should pay attention to the last item in @DmitryLedentsov post - try to ignore the condescending tone - making up the insert SQL string using string append functions is very dangerous as it means anyone who can type into you input can get at anything in your database. Look up SQL injection in google.

Answer (score 1):

It's just about everything not optimal about this code. If you're doing something simple, sonsider using an available wrapper, such as [hiberlite](https://github.com/paulftw/hiberlite/). There are more low level ones as well.

Try to read about clean code first and about [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) and then about [patterns in enterprise software](http://martinfowler.com/articles/enterprisePatterns.html)

This is also not what "[modern](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/)" [C++](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) is good for. Do you really want to do it in C++?

Then, you're doing something dangerous as well - you're assembling a query from a string by not using [value binding](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Comment: I really want to do it in C++ because I like C++. I decided to remove code all and rewrite them, try to make it more clean. Thank you.